# MAPIInitialize fails

Tags: c++

Under Windows 7(64bit) & Outlook 2010(64bit), I call MAPIInitialize to
initialize MAPI, but there will always be a popup message saying:

```
"Either there is no default mail client or the current mail client
cannot fulfill the messaging request.Please run Microsoft Outlook and
set it as the default mail client."
```

Then MAPIInitialize will return
0x80004005, indicating fail to initialize MAPI.

The same program works under Windows Vista(32bit) & Outlook 2007(32bit).

What is the problem? Thanks.

Comment: Did you try to *run Microsoft Outlook and set it as the default mail client*?

Comment: Hi Hamidi, yes I did, but not successful :(